# How can i get lat and long from city name byt NOT with google geocoding?

Tags: api

So I want to swap the city name typed from the user into lat and long, there is API but not google geocoding?

Answer (score 0):

There are many services that you can use. One of the easiest to use packages in Python is GeoPy, whose [documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.geocoders) has a list of many Geolocation services.